# Acumatica - Generic Inquiries - printing Output Reports

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to print output reports from a Generic Inquiry page? The use case would be for our users to review a GI, sort/filter as they desire, then print the result set through an output report. They need the data to be presented and formatted in a specific presentable way (which also includes pictures that would be typically brought into the report).

In a perfect world, we would add a "Reports" Menu to the GI screen that will show all the different types of reports we would allow for them to select.

I know we can build our own custom screens to accomplish this, but our hope is to develop a more generic way on top of the generic inquiries so that everything doesn't have to be so custom each time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generic inquiry is not a report. What that means concretely is that a generic inquiry is restricted to tabular display format. The most common reporting file format for tabular data is XSLX (Microsoft Excel Open XML) which can be exported with the Export Excel button:
[image]

With reports you need to define the tables and relationships in the Report Editor Schema Builder so there's no single report that apply to all generic inquiries. You need to create a specific report and configure the schema to match the records the generic inquiry is selecting. This can be generated with the generic inquiry Export As Report feature:
[image]